# c# access elements of list passed as object type

Tags: c#, list, object, reflection

I want to access members of lists passed in as "object" (the function is handling other data types such as arrays as well). Unfortunately, while this works:

```
List<object> objectlist = new List<object> { "1", "2" };
object res = ((List<object>)((object)objectlist))[0];
```

this does not:

```
List<string> strlist = new List<string> { "1", "2" };
res = (string)((List<object>)((object)strlist))[0];
```

though it DOES work with arrays.

It does not appear to be possible to convert regular lists to List.

Is using reflection (but with GetMethods to avoid repeated string searches):

```
MethodInfo info = ((object)list).GetType().GetMethod("get_Item");
object s1 = (object)info.Invoke(((object)list), new object[] { 0 });
```

the only way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

No, a `List<string>` isn't a `List<object>`... although it *is* an `IEnumerable<object>` due to generic covariance. However, a `List<int>` isn't even an `IEnumerable<object>` as covariance doesn't apply to value type type arguments. Fortunately, it *is* an `IEnumerable`.

So to get the first element of an arbitrary object which you know implements `IEnumerable`, I'd just use:

```
object first = ((IEnumerable) source).Cast<object>().First();
```

(Due to `IEnumerator` not implementing `IDisposable`, more "manual" ways of doing it end up being a bit fiddly.)

Answer (score 1):

`List<T>` implements non-generic `IList`. If you only want to retrieve items from the list, you can cast to it. One-dimensional arrays implement it too, so the cast will work for both arrays and lists

```
res = (string)((IList)((object)strlist))[0];
```